# running a working script from a GUI Button

Tags: modeling, python, panel

I'm working on a script for creating Bravais-grids in Blender. The script works just fine when i run it from the text editor, but when I try to run it from the GUI I wrote it crashes within the grid creating process. The script creates an object wich has vertices on the grid points and parents a base, given by some base vectors, to these vertices.

Support-Class Vector:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coords = list(coords) 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.coords)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if len(other.coords) != len(self.coords):
            raise ValueError("NEIN")
        new = []
        for index in range(len(self.coords)):
            new.append(self.coords[index] + other.coords[index])
        return Vector(new)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        new = []
        for coord in self.coords:
            new.append(coord * other)
        return Vector(new)

    def tup(self):
        return tuple(self.coords)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return all([self.coords[i] <= other.coords[i] for i in range(3)])
```

Crystal generating class:

```
from bpy import *
import bmesh
import random

class Crystal:

    def __init__(self, prim_vecs, base_vecs, kristal_size = \
        [10, 10, 10], base_atom_sizes = [], name = "Crystal"):
        self.prim_vecs = prim_vecs
        self.kristal_size = kristal_size
        self.name = name
        self.mats = []
        self.base_vecs = base_vecs

        while len(base_atom_sizes) < len(base_vecs):
            sizes.append(0.1)
        self.base_atom_sizes = base_atom_sizes

        number_of_mats = len(data.materials)
        for i in range(len(base_vecs)):
            if i > number_of_mats - 1:
                data.materials.new(name="mat%s"%i)
                self.mats.append(data.materials.new(name="mat%s"%i))
                rgb = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
                index = random.randint(0,2)
                rgb[index] = float(random.randint(0,200))
                rgb = tuple(rgb)
                self.mats[-1].diffuse_color = rgb
            else:
                self.mats.append(data.materials[i])

        for index in range(len(self.base_vecs)):
            self.__create_atom_grid(index)
            self.__fill_atom_grid(index)

    def __create_atom_grid(self,index):
        mesh = data.meshes.new("mesh")
        obj = data.objects.new(self.name + "_" + \
        str(self.base_vecs[index]), mesh)

        scene=context.scene
        scene.objects.link(obj)
        scene.objects.active=obj
        obj.select=True

        # the following order works if executed by script
        # if executed by the panel context.object is None
        mesh=context.object.data
        # Exception were caused by the order above
        bm=bmesh.new()

        for x in range(-self.kristal_size[0],self.kristal_size[0]+1):
            for y in range(-self.kristal_size[1],self.kristal_size[1]+1):
                for z in range(-self.kristal_size[2], self.kristal_size[2]+1):
                    vec = vecs[0]*x + vecs[1]*y + vecs[2]*z
                    vec = vec + self.base_vecs[index]
                    if all([0 <= vec.coords[i] <= self.kristal_size[i] for i in range(0,3)]):
                        bm.verts.new(vec.tup())

        bm.verts.new((0, 0, 0))
        bm.to_mesh(mesh)
        bm.free()
        return True

    def __fill_atom_grid(self, index):
        master = data.objects[self.name + "_" + \
            str(self.base_vecs[index])]

        mat = self.mats[index]

        obj = self.__create_atom(Vector((0, 0, 0)),\
        self.base_atom_sizes[index],mat)

        obj.parent = master
        master.dupli_type = "VERTS"
        return True

    def __create_atom(self,vec,radius,color = False):
        ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location = vec.tup(), size = radius)
        obj = context.active_object
        if color:
            obj.data.materials.append(color)
        return obj
```

executed by script:

```
bravis = {  "bcc": [(-1, 1, 1),(1, -1, 1),(1, 1, -1)],
            "sc":  [(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)],
            "fcc": [(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)]}

base_vecs = [(0,0,0)]
base_vecs = [Vector(base_vec) for base_vec in base_vecs]
sizes = [0.1]

#vecs = [(-1, 1, 1),(1, -1, 1),(1, 1, -1)]
vecs = bravis["sc"]
vecs = [Vector(vec) for vec in vecs]
kristal_size = [6, 6, 6]

cryst = Crystal(vecs, base_vecs, kristal_size, sizes)
```

The Gui:

```
bl_info = {
    'name': 'Creating a Crystal-Panel'
}

import bpy
import main_2 as m2       

class Create_Crystal(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'mesh.add_crystal'
    bl_label = 'Add Crystal'
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}


    def execute(self, context):
        bravis = {  "bcc": [(-1, 1, 1),(1, -1, 1),(1, 1, -1)],
            "sc":  [(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)],
            "fcc": [(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)]}

        base_vecs = [(0,0,0)]
        base_vecs = [m2.Vector(base_vec) for base_vec in base_vecs]
        sizes = [0.1]

        vecs = bravis["sc"]
        vecs = [m2.Vector(vec) for vec in vecs]
        kristal_size = [6, 6, 6]

        cryst = m2.Crystal(vecs, base_vecs, kristal_size, sizes)
        return {"FINISHED"}

class Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "panel.crystalPanel"
    bl_label = "Add Crystal"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "render"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("mesh.add_crystal", icon='MESH_CUBE', text="Add Crystal")

def register() :
    bpy.utils.register_class(Create_Crystal)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Panel)

def unregister() :
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Create_Crystal)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Panel)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    register()
    #unregister()
```

The errormessage is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\GUI (1).py", line 27, in execute
  File "\main_2.py", line 62, in __init__
  File "\main_2.py", line 77, in __create_atom_grid
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I belive blender is swiching from object to edit mode when the order is executed by the panel.

Edit:
I found a word around by avoiding the command (in Crystal generating class):

```
 mesh=context.object.data
```

mesh was already defined by:

```
mesh = data.meshes.new("mesh")
```

futher I had a mistake in the Crystal generating class. I try to use the variable vecs while it has to be called with self.prim_vecs:

```
vec = vecs[0]*x + vecs[1]*y + vecs[2]*z
```

Correct:

```
vec = self.prim_vecs[0]*x + self.prim_vecs[1]*y + self.prim_vecs[2]*z
```